# Common Library in android for sharing in social media?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, share

I am developing an android application and I want somethings to share in facebook,twitter,google+,etc
So I want to know if there is any common library available to share in all social media rather than implementing individual sdk's
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a free common library available. I used to integrate facebook , twitter , linkedin , myspace in my application.

The project also says they are looking to add more social clients soon.

https://github.com/socialize/socialize-sdk-android

Answer (score 2):

It is always preferable to use Intent with ACTION_SEND.

```
/* Example of sharing an image */
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out my photo");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a common SDK for all together. But i recommend you to use individual SDks, because they keep on updating their SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a such a library (yet) that allows you to share on multiple social networks.

The best possible solution is to integrate individual SDK's and then allow the user to choose which platform they want to post on. Something like the [TweetDeck App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thedeck.android.app&hl=en).

AFAIK, Google+ does not have an API / SDK with write features. They still, I believe, are in a *Read Only* state.